Airflow Scheduler stuck on restarting with really high CPU
I have a container that is stuck in a "restarting" loop. I get this reoccurring error message right before it dies and starts anew.
[2024-10-03T09:46:09.117+0000] {scheduler_job_runner.py:256} INFO - Exiting gracefully upon receiving signal 15
....
sys.exit..
....
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/executors/local_executor.py", line 407, in end
    self.impl.end()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/executors/local_executor.py", line 351, in end
    self.queue.put((None, None))
  File "<string>", line 2, in put
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 821, in _callmethod
    conn.send((self._id, methodname, args, kwds))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 206, in send
    self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 427, in _send_bytes
    self._send(header + buf)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 384, in _send
    n = write(self._handle, buf)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

I tried docker restart -t 0, I also tried killing the container, I also pulled and redeployed the docker image. All dags are paused, so there is no active workload at the moment. CPU is at 1400%.
Nothing seems to be working.
Any insight is appreciated.

@UlrichEckhardt Would you be so kind to provide how you would debug the issue? What other info would you require? Image has not been updated for months. This is an issue from today.

For a start, extract a [mcve].
